# Drupal wants to install after duplication of Drupal site to subdomain

Tags: mysql, database, drupal, migration

So I have a Drupal website at website.org, and I'm creating a new site, but I want to be able to access the old site (password-protected), as it has important data, so I created a subdomain at old.website.org and pointed it to home/old/public_html, and copied all the files over.

When I try to access old.website.org, I get the drupal install page. After some Googling, I found out that this is likely because Drupal can't access (or otherwise doesn't recognize the existence of) the existing MySQL Database.

Does anyone know why this might occur?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the settings.php file was not copied over for whatever reason. I can't wait to find out what other files weren't copied over! ;)

Follow-up question: why might all the files in the sites/default folder not be copied over when doing a copy via cPanel?

Comment: settings.php file often has more restrictive access rights than other files since it's keeping very sensitive informations. May be that script didn't had right to copy it.